# stop scrolling on mouseup

Tags: javascript, scroll

I made a simple onmouseDown scroll with ScrollBy. Now I cannot stop it before it is til the end.
I would like it to stop scrolling OnMouseUp. I tried somthing but it did not work.
here is thee code:

```
<button onmousedown="skrull();" onmouseup="stop();" style="position:fixed;">Click to scroll <3</button>

<p>Some text and line breaks to enable scrolling!</p>

<script>
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
}
skrull = function skree() {setInterval(scrollWin, 100);}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(skrull);
}
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your interval needs to be stored in a scope that makes it accessible to your `stop()` function. Right now you're calling `clearInterval` on the function `skrull` which returns nothing.

Try something like this:

```
<button onmousedown="skrull();" onmouseup="stop();" style="position:fixed;">Click to scroll <3</button>

<p>Some text and line breaks to enable scrolling!</p>

<script>
var skrullInterval;
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
}
skrull = function skree() {skrullInterval = setInterval(scrollWin, 100);}
function stop() {
    clearInterval(skrullInterval);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great! it worked. thank you for the explanation and clear solution.